# What is the probability that there are three or more consecutive numbers in these six cards?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

52 poker cards (except the red and black jokers), 6 cards are drawn from them. What is the probability that there are three or more consecutive numbers in these six cards?

[The problem have been solved by @BGM in mathematics site.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4265011/520578)
But how to solve this general problem if using mathematica program?

Comment: Your math solution will be a few "n choose k" terms. Take a look at `Binomial` in the docs. If you want help with an Mma implementation, then please add the Mathematica code that you have tried out so far.

Answer (score 1):

It's very slow, but this is my brute force way (ignores draw order otherwise remove the `Sort`):

```
cards = Flatten[Outer[List, Range@13, {♡, ♠, ♢, ♣}], 1];
numbers = cards[[All, 1]];
consecutive[hand_, n_] := Count[Differences@Sort@hand, 1] >= n - 1
numconscv = CountsBy[Subsets[numbers, {6}],consecutive[#,3]&];
numconscv[True]/Total[Values@numconscv]

(* 204853/363545 *)
```

Comment: it seems not right，for the subset{1,1,2,2,7,8}，difference is {0,1,0,5,1}，and the split is 5＞2，but it is false

Comment: @King.Max right, didn't understand _that's_ what you wanted - I was thinking like a straight of 3. I'll update it. Please add examples and more elaboration to your question in future.

Comment: Thanks! I will pay attention next time. In addition, I would like to add that, for example: if you draw {square 1, heart 1, heart 2, club 3, club 4, spades 5} and draw {heart 1, spade 1, heart 2, Clubs 3, Clubs 4, Spades 5} are two different ways to draw poker. Although the numbers of the two results can be written as {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Comment: @King.Max we get the same result if I use ```consecutive[hand_, n_] := 
 Count[Differences[SortBy[hand, First][[All, 1]]], 1] >= n - 1;
numconscv = CountsBy[Subsets[cards, {6}], consecutive[#, 3] &];``` instead, so I've already factored that in, because the numbers `cards[[All,1]]` already contains 4 repetitions of 1..13.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Flinty's solution (and just trying to make a bit faster)....on my laptop, Flinty's solution (above) takes 70.9 seconds, according to `AbsoluteTiming`.

Avoiding the associations in `CountsBy` and instead doing this as a list process reduces the time to 61.9 seconds:

```
(*same as Flinty*)
cards = Flatten[Outer[List, Range@13, {♡, ♠, ♢, ♣}], 1];
numbers = cards[[All, 1]];
consecutive[hand_, n_] := Count[Differences@Sort@hand, 1] >= n - 1
(*change*)
numconscv = Boole@Map[consecutive[#, 3] &]@Subsets[numbers, {6}];
Total[numconscv]/Length[numconscv]
```

Further performance gains can be had by compilin the `consecutive` function; even including the compilation process, this takes only 29.5 seconds:

```
(*same as Flinty*)
cards = Flatten[Outer[List, Range@13, {♡, ♠, ♢, ♣}], 1];
numbers = cards[[All, 1]];
(*change*)
consecutive = Compile[{{hand, _Integer, 1}, {n, _Integer}}, 
   Count[Differences@Sort@hand, 1] >= n - 1];
(*same as in previous example*)
numconscv = Boole@Map[consecutive[#, 3] &]@Subsets[numbers, {6}];
Total[numconscv]/Length[numconscv]
```